# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory when trying to use local package

Tags: python, import, directory, path

Let's consider this directory structure:

```
package/
    rooster.py
    files/
        rooster.txt
app/
    main.py
```

and the content of the two Python files:

rooster.py:

```
def roost():
    file = open('files/rooster.txt')
    return file.read()
```

main.py:

```
from package.rooster import roost
print(roost())
```

Running main.py returns an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'files/rooster.txt'
```

That obviously happens because the working directory is app/ and there's no app/files/rooster.txt file. Thus the error. What solution does Python provide for such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the full path of the file, this should work, if it is always the same

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
I am not sure if I understood the issue correctly, but this code might solve your issue.

**rooster.py**

```
def roost(path):
    import os
    file = open(os.path.join(path, 'files/rooster.txt'))
    return file.read()
```

**main.py**

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from rooster import roost

p = Path(__file__).parents[1]
package_dir = os.path.join(p, 'package')
print(roost(package_dir))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Hello World1
Hello World2
Hello World3
```

**Directory Structure:**

```
testCode/
    package/
        rooster.py
        files/
            rooster.txt
    app/
        main.py
```

Let me know in case there is any issue.